# OpenIndiana cifs server, files created have no permissions

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, cifs, openindiana

I have an OpenIndiana server running napp-it. I have an Ubuntu machine that mounts a CIFS share using this line in fstab:

```
//Storage/Media /storage/media cifs credentials=/home/devians/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

However when this ubuntu machine creates files on the share, they come up like this:

```
???????????  ? ?      ?       ?                ? test
```

If I'm not providing enough info, I will amend this question as comments pop up, since I'm not sure what else is relevant.

Comment: What if the files are created with a windows machine? What if they are created with another linux machine? First thing is to find out whether your client is the problem or a misconfigured share in OpenIndiana.

Comment: I've clearly got some more learning to do, I've opened another question in aim of learning more to answer this one.

Answer (score 1):

OpenIndiana (& most recent Solaris distress in general) use NFSv4 ACLs over CIFS & NFS by default.  What you're seeing is likely normal, more information about that on the [NFSv4 ACL Wiki](http://wiki.linux-nfs.org/wiki/index.php/ACLs).  The reason it is probably showing like that is because CIFS NFSv4 ACLs depends on UID/GIDs to be the same between client & server, much like NFS does.  So the client isn't sure what to make of what the server is telling it.

What you can do is install the `nfs4-acl-tools` to read the ACL on the share.  The biggest question is, can you actually do the things you need to do?  I.E., write to the share?